# How to get distinct of one column and sum of another column in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Query

```
select b.*  from TABLE a, TABLE b 
  where 
    a.hdr_pk_id = b.hdr_fk_id 
      and a.hdr_pk_id in (select bonus_pk_id
    from BONUS_TABLE
        where
            STATUS='I' 
            and TYPE=2 
            )) ;
```

returns sample data:

```
empno empname amount 
1     a       100
2     b       200
3     c       300
1     a       400
2     b       100
3     c       200
```

I need distinct empno and sum(amount)
Eg How can i get the data like

```
empno empname amount
1     a       500
2     b       300
3     c       500
```

Comment: you can use group by empno and then sum on amount

Comment: Are `empno`, `empname` and `amount` the only columns on table `B`?

Comment: no there are many other columns in table B

Comment: @TanmayBinaykiya can you please help with the syntax?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT b.empno, b.empname, SUM(amount) 
FROM TABLE a, TABLE b 
WHERE a.hdr_pk_id = b.hdr_fk_id 
  and a.hdr_pk_id in (select bonus_pk_id
  from BONUS_TABLE
    where
        STATUS='I' 
        and TYPE=2))
GROUP BY b.empno, b.empname;
```

Comment: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"

Comment: The group by was in the incorrect place, this has been updated, please see above.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try

```
 select distinct b.* ,sum(b.amount) over (partition by empname) from TABLE a,TABLE b 
   where 
  a.hdr_pk_id = b.hdr_fk_id 
  and a.hdr_pk_id in (select bonus_pk_id
  from BONUS_TABLE
    where
        STATUS='I' 
        and TYPE=2 
        )) ;
```